# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder Laravel 5.4

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, model, eloquent

Yesterday, I upgraded my biggest application to Laravel 5.4, which is still in Development. In my Frontend, I’m working a lot with Auth::user() and eloquent in my Models. Even if I have some Repositories.

For example I use `Auth::user()->photo('size_256x256')->url` but I'm getting an error.

Under 5.3 it has still worked. The part of the Model looks like 
`return $this->hasOne(UsersPhoto::class, 'user_id', 'id')->where('size', $size)->first();`

Do I have to change a lot now or do I haven’t read something at the change log? Maybe someone has a tipp what's the better way is now.

Comment: You need to show more cod, and then point in the code where the error is happening, and what the error is.

Comment: my error is 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::photo()'. This is the code on my blade 'Auth::user()->photo('size_256x256')->url' and this is my code in my model at photo($size) 'return $this->hasOne(UsersPhoto::class, 'user_id', 'id')->where('size', $size)->first();'

Comment: Are you using the `App\User` class or did you create your own custom class? Does your `App\User` class have the `photo()` method?

Comment: Ok, it's look like something was wrong in Laravel. Now it works after I created Laravel new again.